# Why am I getting the following Redis warning and error?

Tags: node.js, redis

When I try to save the following data to Redis:

```
{ _id: 5c9535a742e1ce2b2ce90be5,
  email: 'admin@admin.com',
  items:
   [ { _id: 5c9535c042e1ce2b2ce90be6, product: [Object], quantity: 1 },
     { _id: 5c9535c642e1ce2b2ce90beb, product: [Object], quantity: 1 } ],
  createdOn: 2019-03-22T19:21:11.349Z,
  __v: 0 }
```

I get the following warning:

```
node_redis: Deprecated: The SETEX command contains a argument of type model.
This is converted to "{ _id: 5c9535a742e1ce2b2ce90be5,
  email: 'admin@admin.com',
  items:
   [ { _id: 5c9535c042e1ce2b2ce90be6, product: [Object], quantity: 1 },
     { _id: 5c9535c642e1ce2b2ce90beb, product: [Object], quantity: 1 } ],
  createdOn: 2019-03-22T19:21:11.349Z,
  __v: 0 }" by using .toString() now and will return an error from v.3.0 on.
   Please handle this in your code to make sure everything works as you 
intended it to.
```

When I try to retrieve the data from Redis, I get the following error:

```
undefined:1
  { _id: 5c9535a742e1ce2b2ce90be5,
    ^
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token _ in JSON at position 2
   at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Function used to save to Redis:

```
exports.setCart = (email, cart) => {
    cart - JSON.stringify(cart);
    redisClient.setex(email, CACHE_TTL, cart);
}
```

Function used to retrieve the data from Redis:

```
exports.getCart = (email, callback) => {
    redisClient.get(email, (err, cart) => {
        if(err) {return callback(err, null)}

        console.log('CART FROM CACHE ', cart)
    return callback(err, JSON.parse(cart));
    })
}
```

Function call to save data to redis:

```
redisClient.setCart(email, cart);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think redis is capable of handling JSON objects directly - especially nested JSONs. You can store a simple JSON object as a hash (by simple I mean that it is a flat JSON with no properties containing other nested JSON objects).

The simplest solution is to `JSON.stringify()` everything before storing them and then `JSON.parse()` them when you retrieve them.

This is fine if your objects are not too big however it is still not ideal. Another option is to use the `flat` npm package that basically flattens your nested JSONs so that they can be stored as hashes. You can see more info about it on [this](https://medium.com/@stockholmux/store-javascript-objects-in-redis-with-node-js-the-right-way-1e2e89dbbf64) Medium article.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, folks, simple syntax error:

```
cart - JSON.stringify(cart);
```

Shoud be:

```
cart = JSON.stringify(cart);
```